# Anonymous union/struct of class with constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unions

GCC complains about this code even though I compile with `-std=c++11` flag, and my gcc version supposedly supports Unrestricted unions (>4.6).

```
union 
{
    struct 
    {
        float4 I,J,K,T;
    };
    struct 
    {
        float4 m_lines[4];
    };
    struct
    {
        float m16f[16];
    };
    struct 
    {
        float m44f[4][4];
    };
};
```

Note that float4 has a non-default constructor that takes 0 parameters.

```
class float4 
{   
    public:
       float4();
 ....
};
```

Any idea of what I could do ? The error is :

```
<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::I’ with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate
```

Comment: Remove the constructor from your `float4` class.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, no, I can’t :)

Comment: c++ has no anonymous structs... it is an extension of your compiler

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Good catch. I confused it with C11, which does allow anonymous structs. I should retract my comment.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to nest these `floats` inside nonstandard anonymous `structs` in the first place? I can't think of any benefit to this. However, of course, maybe I've just overlooked it.

Comment: @underscore_d: I think the idea was to access the inner object without naming it, so if I instantiate an object `obj` which type is the union of all those anonymous struct, I could do something like `b = obj.I`. However had I named the struct I would have had to do `b = obj.foo.I`.
I was porting a very large codebase to gcc, from a compiler which accepted this syntax and refactoring the whole code was too expensive.

Comment: Yeah, at the time of commenting, I had overlooked the fact that your first `struct` declares multiple `floats`, so you couldn't just move all your _struct.float_ members out into the top level of the `union`. It seems your `structs` were achieving some purpose there, albeit a confusing one. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is not the fact that your class `float4` has a constructor, making it a non-POD under the old C++03 definition of POD.  Rather, the issue is that your union and the structs within your union are anonymous.  If you simply name them, it will work:

```
union u
{
    struct s1
    {
        float4 I,J,K,T;
    };
    struct s2
    {
        float4 m_lines[4];
    };
    struct s3
    {
        float m16f[16];
    };
    struct s4
    {
        float m44f[4][4];
    };
};
```

Comment: "it will work". what is the desired goal? you have created an empty union. i doubt that this was desired though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I would like to keep my anonymous structs: this union is nested inside a class and if I change the names, I would have to rename every single call. This code works fine on MSVC10, I wish I could tweak gcc into treating it correctly too.

Comment: @qdii, the problem is that anonymous structs are not valid C++, so you'll run into compiler issues like this all the time if you try to write cross-platform code using them.  It would serve you better to avoid using anonymous structs entirely.

Comment: For anyone reading, this new union has no data members, just 4 inner type definitions that are unused. To get functionality back, declare members with those inner types, including between the closing brace and the semicolon. But `float4` has a non-trivial default constructor, which gives one to `s1` and `s2`, which gives `u` a `delete`d default constructor (if a non-static member of either struct is made).

Answer (score -3):

```
union // This do not need named, it will same to MSVC10 or XCode
{
    struct s1
    {
        float4 I,J,K,T;
    };
    struct s2
    {
        float4 m_lines[4];
    };
    struct s3
    {
        float m16f[16];
    };
    struct s4
    {
        float m44f[4][4];
    };
};
```